# Dependency version not correct in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase, vaadin-flow

I've got a multi-module project set up using maven and Spring Boot. For database migration I'm using Liquibase, but not the Spring Boot integration. I specify my changelogs in code and update the database using new Liquibase().update().

```
Liquibase l = new Liquibase(changelogPath, accessor, database);
    l.validate();
    l.update(new Contexts());
```

My multi-module project ist structured like this:

- parent project (A): specifies dependencies inside
- core (B): sub module of A with some code
- application (C): seperate project, that has B as a dependency

Inside A, I have the following dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.18.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

However, when starting C, I get the exception:

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.parser.core.xml.XSDLookUpException: Unable to resolve xml entity http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd locally
```

After some research, that seems to be the case with liquibase versions lower that 4.12.0. So I checked my dependency tree for project C with IntelliJ tools and found out, that for some reason, C is getting liquibase in version 4.9.1 via dependency of module B and I have no clue why. I also tried to specify version 4.18.0 inside B with no success. When also declaring the version for project C, I get something even weirder:

[Dependency Analyzer for C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgLD.png)

[POM in module B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uct9.png)

[Dependency tree of B inside A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4vNW.png)

Has anyone else had this problem and can provide some inside and solution?

Comment: (a) in multi-module project dependency management section should be declared in the root pom.xml. (b) declare fixed version `<version>[4.18.0]</version>` in dependency management section and skip version declaration in child projects.

Comment: (A) is my root project and it's the only pom where dependencyManagement is declared.
I only tried to declare the version in the other poms because of the weird behaviour I described above.